# How to properly set CMake flags in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm having trouble setting up options and CMake variables and getting them propagated to the CMake GUI.

For example, the following lines are in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -tR -DPOCO_DLL")
message("CMake flags: " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

When running configure in the CMake GUI it prints *"CMake flags: -tM -tR -DPOCO_DLL"* indicating that setting the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "works".

The GUI however don't get updated and only shows *"-tM"* on the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS line.

What is the proper way of setting up these CMAKE options in the CMakeLists file so they get propagated to the CMake GUI?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` *before* `project(...)` statement. But this will not be enough; you will also need to put it into the cache.

Also, if you plan to support setting it initially from the command line interface, and/or `-C` cmake option (locad initial cache), you will need to force put it into the cache, as shown:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -tR -DPOCO_DLL" CACHE STRING "Default CXX options" FORCE)
...
...
project(MyProject)
....
```

On the other hand, be very careful, because you are setting command line options at the moment you know nothing about the compiler, that is by default determined during execution of `project` statement.

Implicitly, this renders your `CMakeLists.txt` compiler dependant.

At the end, here is documentation about [set cmake command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html)